# Source of the dragged item

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

Is there a way to know what is the source of the dragged item?
I.e. we've dragged image from chrome/firefox/etc to the winforms application and at the drop moment I would like to know source(may be handle of the window) of the item(chrome, ff etc).

Comment: You can't find out, part of the D+D contract.

Answer (score 1):

Not by convention.  The more ignorant a drag-drop operation is of its source, the better its design.

It is possible to identify the source by adding extra metadata (strings, etc.) to the drag drop operation using a custom format.  You can try "snooping" on various drag drops using the IDataObject.GetFormats method:

```
    private void Test_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] formats = e.Data.GetFormats();

        foreach (string s in formats)
        {
            try
            {
                string d = (string)e.Data.GetData(s);
                MessageBox.Show(s + "\n" + d);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

Note that in this example I am force casting all the data to strings.  It will usually throw some exceptions because there could also be non-string values attached.  In Google Chrome for example, copying a string offered 8 different data formats, only 5 of which were strings.

If you want to initiate your own drag-drop operations and be able to verify if you are the source, you could use a custom data format for this purpose.

Comment: no, I'm working on drop receiver and can't extend dragable item. So the item provided for me as is. All i want to know - who is the parent of the draggable item?

Comment: A drag operation does not have a parent or a source.  You can only try to hack it in order to identify the source.  You shouldn't need to know the source.  If I had a better idea of exactly why you need to know it and what you're trying to accomplish, there might be a better way to do it.

Comment: I would like to know window title. So here is the simplified task: after dropping an item, application should said where it come from(e.g. dropped from chrome/FF/ie and etc.)  - just title of the window.